# Date picker in Angular 6

Tags: angular6

I am creating a page with date picker in angular 6 using bootstrap. And the constraint is to display calendar icon inside the text box on the right side. Can someone help me on this?.

Answer (score 1):

Use this? https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

If you must use bootstrap (somthing like this):

```
         <form>
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
            <input id="date" type="date" class="form-control" name="date">
          </div>
    ...
</form>
```